# UIButton titleLabel not displaying

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uibutton

I have seen a bunch of similar questions, but noone got the answer I am looking for. When I use this code to make a UIButton and set it's titleLabel, the UIButton appear, but the titleLabel won't appear.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.titleLabel.text = @"Title";
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System-Bold" size:25.0f];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

This code displays the button, but not the titleView, it's title. Why can that be? I am developing for iOS 6 and higher.

NOTE 1: I am not looking for an option like this:

```
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Because I have to use the titleLabel to set it's font and fontSize.

NOTE 2: I can't create a UILabel and add it as a subView of the button. Since the button is later animating.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You always need to specify ControlState when updating button's title!
There are four possible values for UIButtons:

```
UIControlStateNormal
UIControlStateHighlighted
UIControlStateDisabled
UIControlStateSelected
```

so for example:

```
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and then you can set custom settings for titleLabel:

```
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:20.0]];
[button.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: You should use `setTitleColor:forState` for setting the color of the title too (rather than calling `setTextColor` on the `titleLabel`).

Answer (score 10):

```
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Is the correct way to set the title string.

titleLabel is used to set the font and color.

Comment: NOTE 1: I am NOT looking for this answer. I can't use this for the font!

Comment: titleLabel is used to set the font and color for the string that gets set by setTitle:forState:

Comment: Thank you so much, I was searching for this for so long :D

Answer (score 3):

Try using...

```
[button setNeedsLayout];
[button layoutIfNeeded];
```

It will force button to update the layout.

Answer (score 2):

> **If in the storyboard with a custom button image from assets like me**

Check-in Attribute inspector

[image: Asset image as image]

Check-in Attribute inspector set asset image as a background

[image: Asset image as back ground image]

Answer (score 1):

Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write. Use these properties primarily to configure the text of the button. For example:

```
UIButton *button                  = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
button.titleLabel.font            = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode   = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color. Instead, use the setTitleColor(*:for:) and setTitleShadowColor(*:for:) methods of this class to make those changes. To set the actual text of the label, use setTitle(_:for:) (button.titleLabel.text does not let you set the text).
The titleLabel property returns a value even if the button has not been displayed yet. The value of the property is nil for system buttons.

in swift :

```
button.setTitle("your text", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR -** try this `saveButton.titleLabel?.layer.zPosition = 10`

This was a frustrating one for me. I created a UIButton programmatically, added constraints, **and added a gradient background (this is what caused my problem...I think)**. Then I needed to update the font:

```
saveButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
saveButton.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
```

Notice I'm setting the title in the correct way. But still, no title showing. The craziest part - when I clicked "Debug View Hierarchy" I could see the title right there! If I didn't change the font, the title showed as well. Confusing. Then I added this (literally flinging spaghetti and seeing what stuck):

```
saveButton.titleLabel?.layer.zPosition = 10
```

It worked. It seems like some combination of gradient background, setting the font, etc was putting the button's internal title label at the bottom of its layers.